# MissingTemplateException::$file must be string (as in class Exception)

Tags: cakephp-4.x, php-8

I am using `PHP8` and the project is in `Cakephp4`.
For any single `notice` or `warning`, it gives `Template Exception Error` and breaks the project.

```
Fatal error: Type of Cake\View\Exception\MissingTemplateException::$file must be string (as in class Exception)
```

Is there any solution for this issue, so that `notice or warnings` can be excluded and the view will work fine?

Comment: https://book.cakephp.org/4/en/development/errors.html

Comment: When working on php5 or php7, simple warnings or notices are handled automatically and it do not break the view. Why this happens when working with PHP8?

Comment: Please put the errors in the question body, not in the title. The error message says "Fatal error", it doesn't say "Notice" or "Warning".

Comment: The file https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/4.x/src/View/Exception/MissingTemplateException.php has `$file` in the constructor where in PHP8 it has the signature `string $file`. Maybe Cakephp4 is not PHP8 ready

Comment: Please always mention the exact CakePHP version that you are using (last line in `vendor/cakephp/cakephp/VERSION.txt` or run `bin/cake version`). The problem you're seeing has been [**fixed in 4.3.0**](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/pull/15529).

Answer (score 1):

The `Fatal error` comes from the following file:

https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/4.x/src/View/Exception/MissingTemplateException.php

But the problem is already solved in the most current 4.3.0 version,

where the property `$file` got replaced by `$filename` to not conflict with the property `$file` in `\Exception`.

You should update CakePHP and to get rid of the error.

Comment: Strict typing does not affect inherited method signature compatibility behavior, also constructors are exempt from that anyways, and on top of that it's actually valid to not declare the type in an overridden method ;) The problem was the class' `$file` property, and PHP 8.1 changing some exception properties to be typed. This has been [**fixed some time ago**](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/pull/15529), so the user is most likely using an "older" 4.x version.

Comment: "the user is most likely using an "older" 4.x version" => That's why I didnt find `$file` as a property but `$filename`. Thanks for your explanation!